# Automator mac "You do not have permission to move the file to the Trash"

Tags: macos, privileges, automator, macos-mojave

I am stuck with this issue, I can't find a working solution on the web.
I just created a simple Automator application that delete files from my 'Download' folder.

At the last step I got an error:

```
You do not have permission to move the file “Downloads” to the Trash. To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info
```

So I went to *File > Get Info* and I saw that my user has read & write permission and (just to try) I gave the same permissions to everyone but still

```
You do not have permission to move the file “Downloads” to the Trash. To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix this one?

MacOs Mojave 10.14 is my current OS.

thank you so much.

Comment: `Downloads` sounds like the name of the pre-defined downloads folder in your home directory and not like the name of a file. Are you sure you know what you are trying to delete?

Comment: thank you, I really overlooked this...I forgot to insert get folder content and not the actual 'download' folder. really appreciate.